# Help identifying black slope piece with printed knobs, dials, and gauges

Tags: part-identification, piece-information

Can anyone please help with identifying the Design ID as well as the Element ID for this piece. It is a legitimate LEGO piece as can be seen by the name on the studs. However there is no information stamped inside like other pieces. Please help, Google search’s sometimes find the piece but no ID numbers that match with LEGO.
[image: 2x2 brick, 45deg]

Answer (score 7):

Just got off the phone with LEGO. The official answer to this missing piece is as follows:
Design ID#: 80405
Element ID#: 4251812

The official name, according to LEGO, is:
Roof Tile 2x2/45deg, Control Panel

This information was confirmed by set number 10151 and a photo of the piece(same photo posted here).

While I cannot say you will find this piece with the above information, I can say with certainty that it comes directly from LEGO themselves.

Hope this helps others and thank you for the assistance.

Comment: That's great! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: No problem, hope it helps. 

Comment: Keeping in mind 10151 was re-release of 5541, 4251812 Element ID perhaps applies to 10151 set alone. And for earlier sets Element ID for this part could be different. Why? Because re-release of some parts (even if they weren't discontinued) usually gets them different ID.

Comment: LEGO mentioned that. The ID’s are for the 2004 set 10151, the most recent set it was used in...as far as LEGO says. But you are correct regarding earlier sets and ID’s. Based on that though, all anyone can do is decide which to use and go with it. Personally, I go with the most recent so that if I order more, it’s available. Obviously not in this case but in general.

Answer (score 5):

This is [Slope 45° 2 x 2 with 3 Gauges and 3 Knobs](https://rebrickable.com/parts/3039pr9970/slope-45-2-x-2-with-3-gauges-and-3-knobs-print/)

[image: LDraw part render]

Note that this part was last used in [a set](https://brickset.com/sets/10151-1/Hot-Rod) in 2004, so it may not have a known element ID. The instructions for that set do not include a part list with element IDs, and the replacement parts listing on LEGO.com for that set does not include this element.

Comment: Thank you, however none of the sites listing it provide and Element ID. The design ID is 3039 but the print makes it unique. Some printed pieces do not share the same design ID with similar non-printed bricks. That is why I need both ID numbers, to nom properly catalogue it.

Comment: That makes sense. I wasn't able to find an element ID for this part, and I've updated my answer accordingly. Perhaps someone else knows how to access this information.

Comment: Haha, we both went down the same paths. Very aggravating when trying to organize though. Thank you for the help, it at least confirms all that I have been able to uncover with this piece. Hopefully someone else has discovered new clues.

Comment: I don't personally use LEGO element IDs for cataloging pieces, as they aren't available for every element. I use Rebrickable part_num + color_id. Rebrickable does provide a table that maps those values to element IDs in their downloads, so you I can still search by element ID. https://rebrickable.com/downloads/

Comment: This is the first piece that has not had any ID that I have come across. But I did not know about the Rebrickable mapping table, thank you, might come in handy. Will try it with this particular part if nothing else.